# Hid Ribbon on Page, Now Ribbon on Forms is Gone

Tags: ribbon

I have used the `ribbonrowhidetitle` around my ribbon code in my master page, and this hides ribbons on pages as well as on forms, which means my users cant edit now. The reason I needed to hide the ribbon on the pages is I have users who know how to use the "Manage Content" item on the Site Action menu. I am trying to lock down my site. I have used the SPSecurityTrimmedControl2 with `PermissionsString=ManageWeb` which helps but does not remove the Manage Content option so I went with the above. Anyone know how to only hide the ribbon on the pages but not on the forms?

Answer (score 0):

Normally your page uses one master for system pages (like list pages) and one for other pages.

Is this the case for your setup as well? If so, try removing the ribbonrowhidetitle from the system master and see how that turns out.